# change random number into specific range using resolution

Tags: mathematics

I am having a simple mathematical problem that i would like to scale a randomly created decimal points using `numpy` , then apply a formula to align this decimal points to range

range \$:\$-  \$x_\min : x_\max\$

number of points of the interval [xmin : xmax ]  :  ***M***

number of points to be created  :  ***N***

$$ \\resolution = \frac{(x_\max-x_\min)}{M}$$

equation if found \$:\$-

\$t_s\$ \$:\$- *first point*

$$ \\ t_s  = { random *  ( x_\max\ - x_\min\ - N*resolution)}\ $$

i would like to understand this equation

Comment: Yeah, I just got a similar conclusion. If you substitute the formula for resolution into the formula for ts, the result `ts = random * 0` What are the formulas trying to accomplish? The wording sounds like you're trying to constrain your random numbers to be within a given range - is that what you need?

Comment: @Pikalek , yes this is the idea behind what i want to do constraint the values to specific range

Comment: @ahmedosama I corrected the mistake in your question. Note that you are also able to edit your question yourself.

Comment: I still don't understand this question, though. What exactly is the result you expect? As far as I understand, you want N points randomly distributed between Xmin and Xmax. But what is the "resolution" in this context?

Comment: Also, do you need integers or decimal numbers?

Comment: ok , i would like to have decimal points also the resolution is away to add how much the steps can increase relative to the max and min .

Comment: is this the correct formula ?

Comment: i have edited the formula , looks i have misunderstood the formula .

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get a random decimal number selected uniformly from the range [min, max], you can use [`random.uniform(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform)

> `random.uniform(a, b)`
>
> Return a random floating point number N such that `a <= N <= b` for `a <= b` and `b <= N <= a` for `b < a`.
>
> The end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation `a + (b-a) * random()`.

Comment: Thanks , `rando,.uniform(a,b)` provide me with good overview also the equation `a + (b-a) * random()` is so helpful.

In above equation it just uses the resolution of the whole interval . i don't know what is the reason for that , do you think that the resolution add any value on the above equation

Comment: @ahmedosama Honestly, the resolution formula doesn't make sense to me. M is the number of points in the range, but I'm not sure what that is supposed to mean. If you're dealing with decimal #s, then there are an infinite number of points between any two different min max values. If you have any additional information about the formulas (paper, textbook, tutorial, etc), let me know & I'll see what I can come up with. But without any additional context, I'm not how the resolution is intended to work.